# ffmpeg h264_nvenc no cuda-capable device is detected

Tags: server, nvidia, cuda, ffmpeg

I have a mini pc with intel atom cpu and nvidia ion gpu, which I would like to use as encoding/stream server.
The stream part works - I have installed nginx with rtmp and hls modules and when I stream to it from another computer, everything works.
But when I want to encode some video on it and stream it to localhost nginx, there is a problem with h264_nvenc encoder in ffmpeg. I can't use software based encoder on that pc, because that Intel Atom CPU is just too slow to handle it.

When I try to use nvenc by "ffmpeg -re -i path/to/video.mp4 -c:v **h264_nvenc** -vprofile baseline -g 30 -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://address/to/streamserver", stream will fail with error: **no CUDA-capable device is detected**.

My Stream/Encoding Server specs:

- CPU: Intel Atom Dual Core 1,7GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA ION
- RAM: 2GB DDR3
- HDD: 320GB 5400rpm
- OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS
- NVIDIA Driver: 440

Newer drivers than 440 didn't work for me with error, that it works only with 415. or newer, which didn't make sense. Then I found somewhere (don't remember where) that I can install nvidia driver version 440, which solved that error, but got me to this one.

What else I tried was installing CUDA from NVIDIA's site .deb package which didn't work too with the same error. Tried also removing everything NVIDIA/CUDA related through apt and again install CUDA from .deb package.

What else could be done with it to make it work? According to this table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA, ION should be CUDA compatible.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now there is different problem(check my last comment).
I have nvidia driver version 340 working, but can't install cuda 6.5.
It says unsupported compiler.

Is there any other way installing cuda 6.5 without compiling gcc 4.8.1 from source?

Comment: According to Nvidia the latest driver for any ION family product is actually 340.

Comment: I have installed driver version 340.108 from NVIDIA's site and everything NVIDIA related can't communicate with NVIDIA driver, but I need to run nvidia-smi to see which last version of cuda can be installed for this driver. Also I can't install the driver with apt because apt won't find it as it is maybe too old.

Comment: Ok, now installed notebook version of that driver and now it seems nvidia related things can communicate correctly with driver. Smi didn't help me with cuda version, but I found some table somewhere on stackoverflow, that last supported is 6.5. But when I try to install it, it says that I have unsupported compiler(tried also --override, didn't work). I have also found somewhere on forums, that I need GCC version 4.8.1, but that is hard to find built and working.